# shorten functions into one

Tags: jquery

I have a block with three buttons, every button loads a different content. 
How can I shorten those three almost identical functions into one function?

```
$('#mega_online').click(function() {

        $("#contentjq_more").empty().html('<center><img src="http://site.com/image.gif" /></center>');
        $("#contentjq").load("http://site.com/online.php?more=" + $morenum + "&movies=1");
        $("#contentjq_more").empty().html('');
    $morenum = $morenum+20;
        $("#contentjq").show();

});

$('#mega_files').click(function() {
    $morenum = 0;
        $("#contentjq_more").empty().html('<center><img src="http://site.com/image.gif" /></center>');
        $("#contentjq").load("http://site.com/files.php?more=" + $morenum + "&movies=1");
        $("#contentjq_more").empty().html('');
    $morenum = $morenum+20;
        $("#contentjq").show();
});

$('#mega_music').click(function() {
    $morenum = 0;
        $("#contentjq_more").empty().html('<center><img src="http://site.com/image.gif" /></center>');
        $("#contentjq").load("http://site.com/music.php?more=" + $morenum + "&movies=1");
        $("#contentjq_more").empty().html('');
    $morenum = $morenum+20;
        $("#contentjq").show();
});
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried? There is no "problem" here, only a "task". There might be a problem if something *was* tried, and then something  *unexpected* happened. To just get others to look at your code and give suggestions, try a code-review site.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
function DoClick(page)
{
    $("#contentjq_more").empty().html('<center><img src="http://site.com/image.gif" /></center>');
    $("#contentjq").load("http://site.com/" + page + ".php?more=" + $morenum + "&movies=1");
    $("#contentjq_more").empty().html('');
    $morenum = $morenum+20;
    $("#contentjq").show();
}

$('#mega_online, #mega_online, #mega_music').click(function() {
    DoClick($(this).attr('id').split('_')[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I see them as almost identical, you can simply put that out in a function and find the page name as `pageName = this.id.split('_')[1]`.

```
function myFunc() {
        var pageName = this.id.split('_')[1];
        $("#contentjq_more").empty().html('<center><img src="http://site.com/image.gif" /></center>');
        $("#contentjq").load("http://site.com/" + pageName + "?more=" + $morenum + "&movies=1");
        $("#contentjq_more").empty().html('');
    $morenum = $morenum+20;
        $("#contentjq").show();

}
```

and then you can,

```
$('#mega_online, #mega_files, #mega_music').click(function () {
    myFunc.call(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it into a function:

```
function doWork($type) {
        $morenum = 0;
        $("#contentjq_more").empty().html('<center><img src="http://site.com/image.gif" /></center>');
        $("#contentjq").load("http://site.com/" + $type + ".php?more=" + $morenum + "&movies=1");
        $("#contentjq_more").empty().html('');
        $morenum = $morenum+20;
        $("#contentjq").show();
         }

$('#mega_music').click(function() { 
doWork('music');
});

$('#mega_files').click(function() { 
doWork('files');
});

$('#mega_online').click(function() {
doWork('online');
});
```

Comment: You don't have to bind to each element. You can do it in one statement.

Comment: Yea but it's less confusing for a novice.

Comment: No it isn't. It's not hard to comprehend a comma separated list.

Comment: Sure ok. Everyone is different. Personally when I was first learning this stuff it was easy to read and understand what was happening.